# Why does git push all not require remote upstream branch

Tags: git, branch

I created a new branch on my local repo and added a commit to it and then pushed it (along with changed on the master) to my remote repo using `git push --all`, which works fine, i.e. it created a new remote branch with the same name as my local branch and pushed the changes there.

However, when using `git push` whilst having the new branch checked out, it get the `fatal: The current branch ... has no upstream branch.` error.

Why does `git push --all` assume a default branch and `git push` doesn't?

Comment: It's not the case that `--all` "assumes a default branch": it's that `--all` supplies a *refspec* argument for each branch. When running `git push` without a refspec, the `push.default` setting determines how `git push` should behave. When running `git push` *with* one or more refspecs—including the ones implied by `--all`—`git push` behaves differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for `git push` indicates that `--all` will assume defaults for all branches.
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push

> --all:
> Push all branches (i.e. refs under refs/heads/); cannot be used with other <refspec>.

It's not the same for vanilla `git push`. You can, however, specify something like the following in your git configuration to make `git push` default to the current branch.

```
[push]                   
    default = current
```